# Android Launcher app: Is it possible to supply the user with different activities on home press?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-launcher, android-homebutton

I have made a launcher that launches an Activity on home press. However, I want to launch different activities depending on different circumstances. Is it possible to intercept the home-press and assign it a certain activity dynamically within my launcher before ever stating any activity?

What is possible here? I suppose I can `setContentView(something else)`, but I'd rather have completely different activities launched.

Comment: you want diff activity launched on one button ??

Comment: Yes. On home-button. Like a dynamic launcher. All activities would be my own however.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to launch a `Activity` specifically, you could just instantiate `Fragment`s based on your logic. Otherwise, you can have a invisible `Activity` that does some logic quickly, then loads another `Activity`.

Comment: This is what I have; I have an activity launching another, however that causes a lifecycle change (onPause/onResume) in the other Activity, which is annoying because you can press home very rapidly and it causes a lot of these cycles in the launched Activity. Fragments is OK, however I'd rather have a completely new Activity.

Comment: "I'd rather have a completely new Activity" Why's that?

Comment: To make it modular. I just want to put in another activity as I please. Don't mess with fragments and stuff.

Comment: It'd make it more modular. Your call :)

Answer (score 0):

As a launcher, you can. Have a look into the `onNewIntent` callback

> As of GINGERBREAD, if the Activity was already created and a new
>   Intent is being delivered to onNewIntent(Intent), any newly granted
>   URI permissions will be added to the existing ones it holds.

Comment: Well, you *could* hide your default activity and determine to show or open another activity here

Comment: Causes lifecycle change though.